# POSTGRESQL: Count the number of transactions of each extracted month from timestamp for each customer account?

Tags: postgresql

I am having difficulty in attaining what I need. I have come across crosstab and pivot of which are not working in pycharm or maybe postgres no longer uses them. The query for summing works fine but when I try doing the same with COUNT() it instead brings same result for all months, even those with zero counts.

```
SELECT institution_account,
        COUNT(CASE WHEN extract('month' FROM date) = 1 THEN amount ELSE 0 END) AS Jan,
        COUNT(CASE WHEN extract('month' FROM date) = 2 THEN amount ELSE 0 END) AS Feb,
        COUNT(CASE WHEN extract('month' FROM date) = 3 THEN amount ELSE 0 END) AS Mar,
        COUNT(CASE WHEN extract('month' FROM date) = 4 THEN amount ELSE 0 END) AS Apr,
        COUNT(CASE WHEN extract('month' FROM date) = 5 THEN amount ELSE 0 END) AS May,
        COUNT(CASE WHEN extract('month' FROM date) = 6 THEN amount ELSE 0 END) AS Jun,
        COUNT(CASE WHEN extract('month' FROM date) = 7 THEN amount ELSE 0 END) AS Jul,
        COUNT(CASE WHEN extract('month' FROM date) = 8 THEN amount ELSE 0 END) AS Aug,
        COUNT(CASE WHEN extract('month' FROM date) = 9 THEN amount ELSE 0 END) AS Sep,
        COUNT(CASE WHEN extract('month' FROM date) = 10 THEN amount ELSE 0 END) AS Oct,
        COUNT(CASE WHEN extract('month' FROM date) = 11 THEN amount ELSE 0 END) AS Nov,
        COUNT(CASE WHEN extract('month' FROM date) = 12 THEN amount ELSE 0 END) AS Dec,
        COUNT(Amount) AS Total
   FROM transactioning
  GROUP BY institution_account
```

I need some help here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your pivot query is that the `COUNT` functions counts 0 as 1.  So change:

```sql
COUNT(CASE WHEN extract('month' FROM date) = 1 THEN amount ELSE 0 END)
```

to this:

```
COUNT(CASE WHEN extract('month' FROM date) = 1 THEN amount END)
```

If you want to use if/else then use `SUM()` as follows:

```
SUM(CASE WHEN extract('month' FROM date) = 1 THEN amount ELSE 0 END)
```

But note that from Postgres 9.4, the `FILTER` clause is supported.  So I would write your full query as this version:

```sql
SELECT
    institution_account,
    COUNT(amount) FILTER (WHERE extract('month' FROM date) = 1) AS Jan,
    COUNT(amount) FILTER (WHERE extract('month' FROM date) = 2) AS Feb,
    COUNT(amount) FILTER (WHERE extract('month' FROM date) = 3) AS Mar,
    COUNT(amount) FILTER (WHERE extract('month' FROM date) = 4) AS Apr,
    COUNT(amount) FILTER (WHERE extract('month' FROM date) = 5) AS May,
    COUNT(amount) FILTER (WHERE extract('month' FROM date) = 6) AS Jun,
    COUNT(amount) FILTER (WHERE extract('month' FROM date) = 7) AS Jul,
    COUNT(amount) FILTER (WHERE extract('month' FROM date) = 8) AS Aug,
    COUNT(amount) FILTER (WHERE extract('month' FROM date) = 9) AS Sep,
    COUNT(amount) FILTER (WHERE extract('month' FROM date) = 10) AS Oct,
    COUNT(amount) FILTER (WHERE extract('month' FROM date) = 11) AS Nov,
    COUNT(amount) FILTER (WHERE extract('month' FROM date) = 12) AS Dec
    COUNT(Amount) AS Total
FROM transactioning
GROUP BY institution_account
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch man. It works like a charm. I guess I need to understand more when it comes to pivot queries and the likes. Cheers mate.

Comment: If green checkmark to the left is possible, it would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The issue you're encountering with your query is related to the use of the COUNT function. When you use COUNT, it counts the number of rows, and it does not distinguish between the values of amount and 0. This is why you are getting the same result for all months, including those with zero counts.
To achieve your desired result, where you want to count the number of rows for each month while handling the zero counts correctly: you can update the query to:

```
SELECT institution_account,
        SUM(CASE WHEN extract('month' FROM date) = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Jan,
        SUM(CASE WHEN extract('month' FROM date) = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Feb,
        SUM(CASE WHEN extract('month' FROM date) = 3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Mar,
        SUM(CASE WHEN extract('month' FROM date) = 4 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Apr,
        SUM(CASE WHEN extract('month' FROM date) = 5 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS May,
        SUM(CASE WHEN extract('month' FROM date) = 6 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Jun,
        SUM(CASE WHEN extract('month' FROM date) = 7 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Jul,
        SUM(CASE WHEN extract('month' FROM date) = 8 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Aug,
        SUM(CASE WHEN extract('month' FROM date) = 9 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Sep,
        SUM(CASE WHEN extract('month' FROM date) = 10 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Oct,
        SUM(CASE WHEN extract('month' FROM date) = 11 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Nov,
        SUM(CASE WHEN extract('month' FROM date) = 12 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Dec,
        COUNT(*) AS Total
   FROM transactioning
  GROUP BY institution_account;
```

Comment: Hi, and thanks for the suggestion. This won't do what I need since it sums the results of each month instead of counting them. Tim Biegeleisen answer worked for me.